# Any tips on integrating this? $\int \frac {dx} {a\sin^2x + b\cos^2x}$

Tags: integration

I don't really know if this is a duplicate or not, but it may be.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, why the downvote?

Comment: Your question would be must better received if you showed your thoughts on approaching the problem. They would allow people to give answers that clear up any misconceptions and are appropriate for your knowledge level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

$$
\frac{1}{a\sin^2x+b\cos^2x} = \frac{1}{\cos^2 x}\frac{1}{a\tan^2x + b}
$$

Then, use a smart substitution.

Comment: Yeah, thanks! I remember the method now. Did this one in class ages ago and promptly forgot about it.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
& \int\frac{\sec^2 x\,dx}{a\tan^{2}x + b} \\[10pt]
= {} & \int\frac{dt}{at^{2} + b} \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{1}{b} \arctan{\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}\ t} + C
\end{align}

$$t = \tan x$$

In general, try to get an integral into a form where $\tan x$ is there because it's derivative is very convenient.